# Create object array according to changing number of properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I want to handle the array according to number of properties for a category.

I have created an array(array_a) using available properties, and I group that array value according to properties(array_colors,array_sizes). for example now i have two arrays 'array_colors' and 'array_sizes', so in my code I for loop them and created an object array(array_b).
but my issue is I want to handle dynamic number of properties.

```
var array_a = [
   {
  "color":{
     "id":2,
     "name":"Green"
   }
   },
   {
  "color":{
     "id":3,
     "name":"Yellow"
   }
   },
   {
  "size":{
     "id":5,
     "name":"16"
   }
   },
   {
  "size":{
     "id":6,
     "name":"17"
   }
   },
   {
  "size":{
     "id":7,
     "name":"18"
  }
  }
];
array_colors = array_a.filter(function(myObject) {
    return myObject.hasOwnProperty('color');
  });

array_sizes = array_a.filter(function(myObject) {
 return myObject.hasOwnProperty('size');
 });

array_b = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array_colors.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < array_sizes.length; j++) {
array_b.push( {
  "is_available":true,
  "qty":0,
  "price":0,
  "color":array_colors[i],
  "size":array_sizes[j]
});
}
}


array_b = [  
  {  
  "is_available":true,
  "qty":0,
  "price":0,
  "color":{  
     "id":2,
     "name":"Green"
      },
  "size":{  
     "id":5,
     "name":"16",
     "text":"16"
      }
   },
   {  
  "is_available":true,
  "qty":0,
  "price":0,
  "color":{  
     "id":2,
     "name":"Green"
      },
  "size":{  
     "id":6,
     "name":"17",
     "text":"17"
      }
   },
   {  
  "is_available":true,
  "qty":0,
  "price":0,
  "color":{  
     "id":2,
     "name":"Green"
      },
  "size":{  
     "id":7,
     "name":"18",
     "text":"18"
      }
   },
   {  
  "is_available":true,
  "qty":0,
  "price":0,
  "color":{  
     "id":3,
     "name":"Yellow"
      },
  "size":{  
     "id":5,
     "name":"16",
     "text":"16"
      }
   },
   {  
  "is_available":true,
  "qty":0,
  "price":0,
  "color":{  
     "id":3,
     "name":"Yellow"
      },
  "size":{  
     "id":6,
     "name":"17",
     "text":"17"
       }
   },
   {  
  "is_available":true,
  "qty":0,
  "price":0,
  "color":{  
     "id":3,
     "name":"Yellow"
      },
  "size":{  
     "id":7,
     "name":"18",
     "text":"18"
      }
   }
]
```

my expected array as above.I want to handle the properties such as color,size dynamically.

Comment: Are you sure that's your expected output? `'red'` is nowhere in your input (and there don't seem to be many of the properties in the object you're `push`ing to `array_b`?)

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean

Comment: You say your expected output is `array_b = [
{'color':'red','size':16},
{'color':'red','size':17},
{'color':'green','size':16},
{'color':'green','size':17}
] `, but where does `'color':'red'` come from? `'red'` isn't anywhere else in the script, why does it magically appear in the output? Also, `green` is *capitalized* in your input, did you want something to call `toLowerCase` on the color when turning it into `array_b`?

Comment: Your expected output also doesn't contain any properties other than `color` and `size`, but your `.push` attempt has an object that has `is_available`, `qty`, and `price`. Are those properties actually expected in your output or not? Please clarify your question

Comment: sorry, by mistake i have put 'red'. by the way i got the answer. thank you for your kind consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mergeWith) you can merge the properties to a single object with the property names as the keys, and an array of values for each key.
Then [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reduce) the object to an array of objects using [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap) (or [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const array_a = [{"color":{"id":2,"name":"Green"}},{"color":{"id":3,"name":"Yellow"}},{"size":{"id":5,"name":"16"}},{"size":{"id":6,"name":"17"}},{"size":{"id":7,"name":"18"}}];

const getAllCombinations = _.flow([
  arr => _.mergeWith({}, ...arr, (o, s) => _.isArray(o) ? [...o, s.name] : [s.name]),
  props => _.reduce(props, (r, values, k) =>
    _.isEmpty(r) ?
    values.map(v => ({
      is_available: true,
      qty: 0,
      price: 0,
      [k]: v,
    })) :
    _.flatMap(r, o => values.map(v => ({
      ...o,
      [k]: v
    }))), [])
]);



console.log(getAllCombinations(array_a));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).